# GraalVM Native Image failing on Springdoc dependency

Tags: java, spring-boot, springdoc, graalvm-native-image

I am trying to create a sample application using spring boot and GraalVM Native Image, however as soon as I add the dependency for Springdoc the generated executable is no longer working due to the following:

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springdoc.core.SpringDocConfiguration.springdocBeanFactoryPostProcessor2
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:60) ~[poc-graalvm-native.exe:na]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:184) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:144) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:120) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:331) ~[poc-graalvm-native.exe:na]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:236) ~[poc-graalvm-native.exe:na]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:280) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:96) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:707) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:533) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[poc-graalvm-native.exe:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) ~[poc-graalvm-native.exe:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[poc-graalvm-native.exe:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[poc-graalvm-native.exe:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) ~[poc-graalvm-native.exe:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[poc-graalvm-native.exe:na]
        at c.b.t.graal.GraalVMApplicationPoc.main(GraalVMApplicationPoc.java:31) [poc-graalvm-native.exe:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springdoc/core/CacheOrGroupedOpenApiCondition$OnCacheDisabled.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.AbstractNestedCondition$MemberConditions.getMetadata(AbstractNestedCondition.java:149) ~[poc-graalvm-native.exe:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.AbstractNestedCondition$MemberConditions.getMemberConditions(AbstractNestedCondition.java:121) ~[poc-graalvm-native.exe:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.AbstractNestedCondition$MemberConditions.<init>(AbstractNestedCondition.java:114) ~[poc-graalvm-native.exe:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.AbstractNestedCondition.getMatchOutcome(AbstractNestedCondition.java:62) ~[poc-graalvm-native.exe:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47) ~[poc-graalvm-native.exe:na]
        ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springdoc/core/CacheOrGroupedOpenApiCondition$OnCacheDisabled.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
        at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:180) ~[poc-graalvm-native.exe:na]
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.getClassReader(SimpleMetadataReader.java:55) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:49) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:103) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:81) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.AbstractNestedCondition$MemberConditions.getMetadata(AbstractNestedCondition.java:146) ~[poc-graalvm-native.exe:na]
        ... 22 common frames omitted
```

My current dependencies are :

```
dependencies {
    implementation ('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web') {
        exclude group : 'org.apache.tomcat.embed', module : 'tomcat-embed-websocket'
    }
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    // Lombok
    compileOnly("org.projectlombok:lombok")
    annotationProcessor("org.projectlombok:lombok")

    testCompileOnly("org.projectlombok:lombok")
    testAnnotationProcessor("org.projectlombok:lombok")

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j
    implementation('org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:2.0.0-alpha1')
    implementation('org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-webmvc-core:1.4.4')
}
```

Everything was working fine until I added SpringDoc.
Already tried to add some springdoc packages to --initialize-at-build-time without success.

I am using com.github.ayltai.spring-graalvm-native-plugin to handle the gradle task and my dependencies are:

```
dependencies {
    implementation ('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web') {
        exclude group : 'org.apache.tomcat.embed', module : 'tomcat-embed-websocket'
    }
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    // Lombok
    compileOnly("org.projectlombok:lombok")
    annotationProcessor("org.projectlombok:lombok")

    testCompileOnly("org.projectlombok:lombok")
    testAnnotationProcessor("org.projectlombok:lombok")

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j
    implementation('org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:2.0.0-alpha1')
    implementation('org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-webmvc-core:1.4.4')
}
```

Any hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `v1.5.9`springdoc-openapi [fully supports](https://springdoc.org/#graalvm-and-spring-native-for-native-images) GraalVM with spring-native.

No additional configuration required.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the input! I am already using the spring-graalvm-native.
However, adding the resource-config seems to break the native-image compilation:
```Fatal error:java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: Format specifier '%5c' ```

Comment: Ok, it seems like an issue with the gradle plugin that I am using. I just switch everything to maven and it started to give some different errors - I am adding more to resource-config as I write and it seems to be working (or at least partially fixing some issues). Your reply made me more aware of the jsons and when/how to use them.

Answer (score 0):

Add this dependency `springdoc-openapi-native`